# Google Analytics Email Reports

Tags: google-analytics

I am now assigned to support GA reporting. The current email reports show the top 10 pages visited, but the total shows the full total page hits. So if you add up the top ten it does not come up to the total because it is missing page hits that do not belong to the top 10.

I am trying to modify the email reports so they show all page hits on all pages. I have googled and looked at the FAQ's in GA and can not seem to modify the reports. Does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your report is based off a dashboard rather than a generic google analytics report such as the report in Behavior > All Pages.

What you can do is schedule an email based off the Behavior > All Page report by going to that report and selecting the "Email" option.